# HTML / JAVASCRIPT : Disable HTML in contentEditable=true

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML / JAVASCRIPT : Disable HTML CONTENT in contentEditable=true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341044/html-javascript-disable-html-content-in-contenteditabletrue)

I want to know how to disable or control html elements, tags and drag and drop, image resizing and all what comes with contentEditable `contentEditable="true"` element.

Before you ask why: Right click on this page: `Control or Command+A` go to http://jsbin.com/itugu/3 click the text then click `Control or Command+V and the whole stackoverflow is pasted in.

http://www.facebook.com , they are using a `<div>` too instead of `<textarea>` and everything is disabled, that's exactly what I want to know, how they did it? :)

Please if you know any resources, links about this, post it!

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of the one from July 27th? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341044/html-javascript-disable-html-content-in-contenteditabletrue

Comment: Hi @Day the question is the same but with that question I wanted something else, so It's not :)

Comment: Hi CIRK please don't ask the same question over and over.